# Testing a CloseableIterator interface

Tags: java, tdd

What would be some of the ways to test the following interface:

```
interface CloseableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>, AutoCloseable {

}
```

Thanks.

EDIT

I wonder if the following test would be beneficial:

```
    @Test
    void anonymousImplementation() {
        new CloseableIterator<String>() {
            @Override
            public void close() throws Exception {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public String next() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Then, if for any reason `AutoCloseable` is removed from `CloseableIterator`, or generic type is changed to, say, `T extends Number`, it will give me compile error. Not really a "test", but ensures that at least one implementation exists that ensures the methods are correct, and that the generic type is valid.

Comment: There is no code at all, what could you possibly test?

Comment: perhaps write a test that ensures interface contains `close`, `hasNext`, and `next`? maybe just construct an anonymous class

Comment: if you have a generic interface, you could construct anonymous class with explicit type, such as `new Interface<String>`. If the interface is then changed to `interface Interface<T extends Number>`, it would give an error

Comment: your answer was very adequate. dont know what else you could add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written right now, your interface does **not** contain any code (aka behavior).

There is nothing to test therefore.

In other words: at this point in time, there is no reason to write a unit test here. Writing a test only implementation of an interface, just to test that the interface is the interface is overkill. There is no kind of bug that you will ever catch here.

Meaning: if your interface is used the wrong way, the compiler will let you know.

Remember: you don't write unit tests because you can. You write them because they contribute to your work. As explained, at least for the given interface here, unit tests do not contribute meaningful value.